# R Comparing the values of two factors in a data frame and getting the result in a third

Tags: r, if-statement

i am trying to compare the values of two factors in a dataframe and getting the result in a third. I am trying to use a if statement.

Risk is the new column i'm trying to add.

```
 X = within(X, {
  Risk = if(X$Member == "Member" & X$Predict == "Non Member"){
    "Risk"
  } else{
    "No Risk"
  }  
})
```

Comment: Use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` i.e. `with(X, ifelse(Member == "Member & Predict == "Non Member", "Risk", "No Risk"))`

Answer (score 0):

1. using `dplyr`:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   X %>% mutate(Risk = ifelse(Member == "Member" & Predict == "Non Member",
                              "Risk", "No Risk"))
   ```
2. with base R:

   ```
   X$Risk = ifelse(X$Member == "Member" & X$Predict == "Non Member",
                   "Risk", "No Risk")
   ```